# How to define a nested matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I am new to coding and Python and I would be grateful if someone could help me with this problem. I want to define a 200x1 matrix every cell of which is a 8X17 matrix and the cells of this one are 1x3 vectors.

The values in the 1x3 vectors are generated randomly (from different sets of data). I want to run a genetic algorithm and this would define 200 members of my initial populations.

I have tried this in MATLAB using cell arrays; but they significantly slow down my code.

This is what I have tried in MATLAB.

```
P = cell (200, 1);
for i = 1:200
    P{i,1} = cell(8, 17);
    for j = 1:8
        for k = 1:17
            P{i,1}{j,k} = zeros(1,3);
            P{i,1}{j,k}(1,1) = randi(Hmax{j}(k));
            P{i,1}{j,k}(1,2) = randi([Hmin{j}(k),Hmax{j}(k)]);
            P{i,1}{j,k}(1,3) = randi(Wmax{j}(k));
        end
    end
end
```

`Hmin`, `Hmax`, and `Wmax` are 8x17 matrices of data which have been imported as cell arrays. They are simple numbers which provide a range for the randomly generated values in 1x3 vectors.

And for those wondering what MATLAB cell arrays are, see
[Cell Arrays](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you provide the important part of the code you're trying?

Comment: Not sure what a "cell array" is in matlab, but if you use Python lists, I suspect it will be even slower. Now, it *sounds* like you could use true multidimensional arrays, like with `numpy`, although I would have thought matlab handles that, perhaps even faster

Comment: In any case, this really isn't an appropriate question for stack overflow, you are basically asking us to guide you through a python implementation, that is just too broad. Please try to do this yourself, and if you encounter *specific issues*, then ask a question (after checking searching for similar questions that may already exist first, of course)

Comment: This may help you https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Comment: @ThRnk Thank you so much for your comment. I have added the MATLAB code.